# Uncaught (in promise): false

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have the following error when using alert messages for my login menu:

> Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): false Stack Error: Uncaught (in
>   promise): false

This is the code:

```html
  public login() {
    this.showLoading()
    this.auth.login(this.Login).subscribe(allowed => {
      if (allowed) {        
        //this.navCtrl.setRoot('Inicio');
        this.usuarioLogueado = this.auth.getUserInfo();
        if(this.usuarioLogueado.tipo == "Administrador"){
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(Administrador);
        }
        console.log("bienvenido",this.usuarioLogueado.usuario,this.usuarioLogueado.tipo);
      } else {
        this.showError("Acceso denegado");
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }

  showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Por favor espere...',
      dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    this.loading.present().then(() => this.loading.dismiss());
  }

  showError(text) {
this.loading.dismiss().catch(() => console.log('ERROR: Control de loading fallo'));
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Fallo',
      subTitle: text,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present(prompt);
  }


}
```

Comment: Please add your code to your question.  It is not appropriate to link to a picture of your code.

Comment: Reason being that the page might not exist later on and the next person that has the same issue will not be able to see your code.

Comment: i add the code.

Comment: It is thrown from this.loading.dismiss() or this.alertCtrl.create()? However, this should be an issue inside the JS library you are using. May submit a bug report to them.

Comment: i dont know from where it comes, since it does not specify. :(

Answer (score 3):

I think the error is related to this line of code:

```
this.loading.present().then(() => this.loading.dismiss());
```

I'm not sure why you would like to hide the loading as soon as it becomes visible. The proper way to use a loader, would be to show it before making the http request, and hide it when the request has ended. It'd look like this:

```
// Assuming you already have a property to hold the instance of the loader 
public loading: any;

public login() {
    this.showLoading().then(() => { // Show the loading before making the request

        this.auth.login(this.Login).subscribe(allowed => { // Make the http request

            this.loading.dismiss().then(() => { // Hide the loading

                if (allowed) {

                    // this.navCtrl.setRoot('Inicio');
                    this.usuarioLogueado = this.auth.getUserInfo();

                    if (this.usuarioLogueado.tipo == "Administrador") {
                        this.navCtrl.setRoot(Administrador);
                    }

                    console.log("bienvenido", this.usuarioLogueado.usuario, this.usuarioLogueado.tipo);

                } else {
                    this.showError("Acceso denegado");
                }
            });
        }, error => {
            this.loading.dismiss().then(() => { // Hide the loading
                this.showError(error);
            });
        });
    });

}

showLoading(): Promise<any> { // <- Return the promise
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Por favor espere...',
        dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    return this.loading.present(); // <- Added the return keyword here
}

showError(text) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Fallo',
        subTitle: text,
        buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present(prompt);
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Since it fixed the issue, please mark the answer as the accepted answer so we can close the question.